# Angular 2 - Change template in differents pages

Tags: angular, routes

Im developing a dashboard, and I want 2 kinds of pages layouts, one with a navigation bar and other things, and other without that, for example for use in login.

I want urls like this:

- host/login (without navigation bar)
- host/configuration (with navigation bar)

I think that I cant use routing childs to accomplish this because I will get urls like:

- host/no-navigation/login
- host/navigation/configuration

I am right? How can I do it?

Comment: You need a service to set whether the component is shown

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly, what you need:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed.git
```

see the source files unter `src/client/app` beginning with `app.component.ts` and in it's template `app.component.html` you will see an example:

```
<sd-toolbar></sd-toolbar>
<sd-navbar></sd-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You can show and hide any part of an html file with `*ngIf` like `*ngIf="userLoggedIn"`

you can start and test the seed:

```
$ cd angular-seed
$ npm install
$ npm start
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I´m currently doing something like this, but in fact I want to manage different layouts in the same depth of the url, in this case is the same layout.

Comment: You can manage 10^x layouts and change the layouts dynamically, that's no problem. You have to take some time and go deeper,..